# Notation meaning:$ R(x^2 + x +1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm doing a problem sheet on rings and ideals, and would appreciate clarification on some notation used.

The problem is:

"Let $R=\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$, the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.
For the ideal $I = R(x^2 + x +1)$, show that $R/I$ has four elements and deduce that it is a field."

What does $ R(x^2 + x +1)$ denote?

Looking through my lecture notes and appealing to Google hasn't helped.

Comment: If $R$ is the set of polynomials having $0,1$ as coefficients, then computing the set of such polynomials modulo $x^2+x+1$ should yield a very small set of classes

Comment: For $R=\mathbb Z_2[x]$, $R(x^2+x+1)$ simply means the set of all things of the form $f(x)(x^2+x+1)$ where $f(x)$ is in $R$, so in other words all things of the form $f(x)(x^2+x+1)$ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb Z_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R(x^2+x+1)=\{r\cdot (x^2+x+1) \mid r\in R\}$.  This is the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^2+x+1$.  That is, it consists of all (polynomial) multiples of $x^2+x+1$ in $R=\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.